# Is the "feed" role also appropriate for the "Load More" button approach?

Tags: accessibility, infinite-scroll

Both [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#feed) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Feed_Role) seem to associate the `feed` role with infinite scrolling, without mentioning if it applies to button-triggered loading as well (with a "Load More" button).

My application shows products on a grid, appending more items to it each time the button is pressed. I'd like to know if the `feed` role would work (and be beneficial) in this case.

I missed a paragraph at w3.org where it says:

> Alternatively, authors MAY include an article at either or both ends
> of the loaded set of articles that includes an element, such as a
> button, that lets the user request more articles to be loaded.

I think that means it applies to my case. Great!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is already contained in the question.